# Does Beta distribution act more generally than I reckon?

Tags: probability, statistics, mathematical-modeling, data-analysis

In Bayes theory, Beta distribution is often introduced to make the assumption for parameter p which is from Binomial(N,p). My question is whether Beta distribution can model all probability or ratio in a random process or it should only be applied to a p under the context of a Binomial process?

Thanks heaps

Comment: Beta distributions are the [conjugate priors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior) for the probability parameter of Bernoulli, binomial, negative-binomial and geometric distributions, which makes it analytically easier to use than other priors in these cases. It could theoretically also be used in other cases where a parameter needs to take values in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Beta PDF's have an extremely wide variety of shapes, and so can describe many practical distributions with support $(0,1).$ Also, four-parameter (or 'extended') beta distributions have support on intervals $(A, B),$ with $A < B.$ See Wikipedia on 'beta distribution'. For example, extended beta distributions with $A=-1$ and $B=1$ can model a prior distribution on a correlation coefficient $\rho.$

Comment: Thank you both,  your comments really help and convince me to go ahead. Sincerely